# HTML figcaption element position

Tags: html, css, web

I have the following code:

```
       <html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <head></head>
        <style>
            .outerCss{
      background-color:#f2f2f2;
      border-radius:5px;
      margin-left: inherit;

    }
    h1{
      text-align:center;
      font-family:Monospace;
    }
    h3{
      text-align:center;
    }
    .imageOption{
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #innerContainer{
      background-color:antiquewhite;
      border-radius:5px;

    }
    .dates{
     width: 50%;
     margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    figcaption{
      float: inherit;
    }
        </style>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container" id="innerContainer">
      <h1>Dr.Norman Borlaug</h1>
      <h3><i>The man who saved a billion lives</i></h3>
      <div class="row">      
        <figure>
        <img class="imageOption center-block" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg">
        <figcaption>Dr. Norman Borlaug, second from left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</figcaption>
        </figure>   
      </div>
      <h3>Here's a time line of Dr. Borlaugs's life:</h3> 
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that, I put the image at the center but cant move the `figcaption` , so that to start from the point where the image starts. Sorry if it is a dumb question, just started learning them and dont know really how to search for an answer about it, I am not that familiar with the terminologies.

Comment: Share your CSS, otherwise this should be closed as offtopic. You need to share a **working example**

Comment: To the person who voted as duplicate, you could at least post some comment with duplicated link

Comment: I'm confused, your question is not very clear -- `<figcaption>` is a child element of `<figure>` so placement and position values should be set for *figure* and will be inherited for *figcaption*. Also try using `text-align:center` on figcaption if applicable.

Comment: @Martin thanks it worked with text-align:center;

Comment: @imoteb nobody vote this as duplicated. Someone vote this as offtopic, and before your edition this fits exactly with offtopic. However, he needs to retract the vote since this is solved